# get Google Adwords developer token programmatically

Tags: google-ads-api

I have google oauth2 authorization. To work with google adwords, I need developer token. I can see it on the website in my account, but is there any way to find it programmatically through the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google support replied that now there is no such possibility https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/RLpvEMFay4s/Wm75mEj9BAAJ